# jquery/javascript to listen for a 3rd party plugin overlay to be closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using a 3rd party jquery plugin which when called from a page, pops up with an overlay, and some forms that are not part of my site.

I've been trying (with no joy so far) to be able to detect from my own sites jquery, when this overlay is closed. I'd like to simply jump to a certain part of the page.

I've tried writing jquery to listen for the final button of the 3rd party form being closed, by checking for it's class name being removed, with .remove .destroy and checking for it's existing with .length and some other methods. however, it seems that my on page jquery can't see anything about these elements at all, and therefor I can't do something fun when that dialogue ends.

Anyone got any ideas of how this could be achieved? Am I missing something obvious?

Cheers in advance!

Comment: This is quite broad. It's hard to suggest anything without knowing what plugin you're using or seeing any of your code or markup.

Comment: It's a diary booking plugin which isn't available publicly. I guess the content of the plugin I felt wasn't so important. Just trying to find a way to trigger that the process was finished, and the user is back on the webpage. The plugin forms have several buttons etc, and I've tried firing javascript on those buttons via onclick, but it just seems my javascript can't see those on the DOM which I found strange, as they are.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working via the below javascript. Maybe there is a better way, but this seems to be working well

```
<script>
    var bookingInterval;
    $("#ViewingButton").click(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            bookingInterval = setInterval(function () {
                if ($(".agent-ui-modal")[0]) {
                    // Do nothing if class exists
                } else {
                    // Do something if class does not exist
                    window.location = ("#calculator");
                    stop();
                }
            }, 500);
        }, 5000);
    });

    function stop() {
        clearInterval(bookingInterval);
    }
</script>
```